# Travelling for an academic seminar with a 36*48 inch poster board on a flight

Tags: poster

I need to attend a competition\seminar with my teenage son. He needs to create a project for this competition on a 36"*48" trifold poster board. Now the dimensions of this trifold poster board do not make it eligible for taking it as a carry on luggage and its not safe to send it in Checked in luggage for risk of damaging the project that he has done. What are the options for carrying this poster board as a carry on luggage ?

Comment: To the person who flagged this as a duplicate, could you leave a comment pointing to the other question? This question is not a duplicate of any of the questions tagged [tag:poster].

Comment: From my experience (UE) often even though the regulations about baggage size are strict for other stuff, always I managed to bring a poster (even with some cheap airlines); and it fits neatly under chairs or in the overhead lock. Through, there is always some risk.

Comment: I didn't flag this as a duplicate, but perhaps this was the question the flagger had in mind: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/flying-with-a-poster-tube-as-a-hand-luggage

Comment: For context: the OP originally posted this question as an answer (now [deleted](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10205/64) ) to the question I linked to above, and a moderator recommended that he or she ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 10):

One common option is to print or create the poster on a large sheet of paper and carry it in a [poster tube](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/flying-with-a-poster-tube-as-a-hand-luggage).  After you arrive at your destination, buy a blank poster board, and paste your paper onto it.

Answer (score 6):

Another option that goes beyond Nate's idea and that would work in an American city: take the poster as a PDF, find a local Kinko's and then print it out. Then apply Nate's solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have shipped posters to my hotel before. UPS/FedEx/...will drop your poster at the lobby. It will be waiting for you when you get there...